Exporting coeftable to stargazer for regression table
I am working with regression models of a class not supported by stargazer.
Below is the model I am working with:
data(mtcars)
model.fixest <- feols(mpg ~ hp + drat + wt, data=subset(mtcars))

I can dilute down the basic statistics to the following table
model.fixest[["coeftable"]]
              Estimate  Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 29.3949345 6.156303365  4.774770 5.133678e-05
hp          -0.0322304 0.008924543 -3.611434 1.178415e-03
drat         1.6150485 1.226982656  1.316277 1.987554e-01
wt          -3.2279541 0.796398312 -4.053190 3.642961e-04

Is there any way I could graft these values onto a regression model?
I am looking for my outcome regression table to look something like this. (Right here i am using fixest's etable  command for illustration purpose)
> etable(model.fixest)
                      model.fixest
Dependent Var.:                mpg
                                  
Constant          29.39*** (6.156)
hp              -0.0322** (0.0089)
drat                 1.615 (1.227)
wt              -3.228*** (0.7964)
_______________ __________________
S.E. type                      IID
Observations                    32
R2                         0.83688
Adj. R2                    0.81940
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1


Best
